# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar una carpeta desde la pagina de GitHub o desde la terminal?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, repositorio

Necesito su ayuda.

**¿Cómo puedo eliminar una carpeta desde la pagina de GitHub o desde la terminal?**

Subí una carpeta desde la pagina de git hub (se llama *img*) en la seccion donde dice **Add file**, despues le puse donde dice **Upload files** arrastre la carpeta y le puse **Commit changes**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedo así, pero me arremetí y ahora decesito borrar esa carpeta del repositorio, como le hago?

Para que ya solo quede el archivo README.md

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacerlo de esta forma:

Para eliminar la carpeta

```
git rm -r img
```

Y agregas el cambio hecho al stage:

```
git add .
```

Creamos el commit

```
git commit -m "Elimino carpeta img"
```

y subes los cambios al repositorio con

```
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

Para eliminar la carpeta se debe ingresar a ella, y en el lado superior derecho, en las opciones mostradas por la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los tres puntos, haces clic en la opción "Delete directory"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego se selecciona el botón "Commit changes", y se eliminará la carpeta.

Answer (score 0):

No puede eliminar toda la carpeta a la vez. Pero si elimina todos los elementos dentro de la carpeta `img`, la carpeta desaparecerá automáticamente si está vacía.